# How turn off or removed - org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.release=disabled from .settings

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

How can I totally turn off or remove this line in

->.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs---->org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.release=disabled

The reason why I need it to remove, it does not allow one of cucumber plugin working as it should be! On my other laptop, I do not have this line and everything works perfectly! Project the same!
And after update Maven it creates again! Found on the internet that it is some settings in Eclipse, but not sure where exactly it is!
Thank you!

Comment: I guess that is in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ the _Use '--release' option_ checkbox.

Comment: Thank you, but it is by default unchecked!

Comment: The release option exists since Eclipse Photon, so probably the Eclipse version on your laptop is older. I don't think this line is the root cause (does it work if you remove the line manually after updating Maven?). I would guess the issue is related to the installed and used JRE version. Which Java version do you exactly use on your PC and on your laptop?

Comment: Yes, I have photon on one laptop and on other 4.7 version of the eclipse! But the reason I think that it is the problem, once it was pulled on the laptop with the version 4.7 the same project and with that line - the function in feature file (command+click on step) stop working! But on version photon, it was never worked before and I am looking the way to fix that. I also tried to go back to version 4.7 and still not working! So somewhere in settings problem or now I think maybe in java kit! I use 1.8 and on 4.7 the same! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just change cucumber plugin from Natural to io.cucumber and it is working better as it should be and with that, I do not need to change any settings for the eclipse.